# Run database-hitting code on every boot in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I need to run some code every time Laravel receives some sort of request.
This may be an HTTP request, console command or queue event.

The code needs to access the database.

While Service Providers may be the appropriate in similar situations, I'm experiencing a bunch of problems running DB hitting code in them.

In earlier versions of Laravel it was possible to hook into App Lifecycle Events. This does not seem to possible anymore.

Middleware also only applies to HTTP requests.

Any ideas on how to approach this are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of problem did you experience with service providers? The first thing that popped to my mind was create a service provider that does something with the database. It will be called in case of HTTP request, CLI command or queue event. Seeing you ruled out one possible and very likely solution - why? What kind of problem did you face and how did you hope to avoid the same problem using a different approach?

Comment: The main problems I experience relate to the fact that Laravel is unable to boot when the database does not yet exist. This may be while testing or during deployment.

So the migrations need to run, everything needs to be set up, and only then should Laravel run the query.

Comment: "*Laravel is unable to boot when the database does not yet exist.*" - this isn't true. It boots just fine. The problem **appears** to be that you're assuming you migrated the database and you're trying to access it, without knowing it's there. Whether you use a Service Provider or any other approach, you'll have the same problem. The solution to your problem is to check if a table exists and if you're able to connect before executing the rest of your code. [Refer to following documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables).

Comment: You are absolutely right about that. I've tried checking if `Schema::hasTable('users')` which _appears_ to work fine, but for some reason causes sqlite to lock the database when database migrations are run during a test. So right now I need to check if the table exists and if the environment `!== 'test'`, which doesn't seem perfect at all. Thanks for all your help!